# Does MUI have render function in table as antd?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd

I want to render my own component in MUI table if you have used antd library, It has render function in Table.Column, I need similar function, does Mui table have it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at MUI Table Documentation. Follow the link where you find an example what you are looking for. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#data-table  Have a look at `valueGetter`.